# Changing google maps display options for multiple maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, joomla, google-maps-api-3

I have a series of maps in a Joomla-based website (there is a map per event and my client needs to upload maps all the time), and I need to remove the "Map Satellite Terrain Earth" buttons. 
I can imagine how to do it for one map (using APIv3 and JS, writing a code that includes coordinates and hides controls), but I need to make a JS file that can be applied for all the maps in the page.

This is for example one of my maps:

```
<iframe src="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Jurys+Inn+Birmingham,+245+Broad+Street,+Birmingham&amp;aq=0&amp;sll=52.476821,-1.911922&amp;sspn=0.010573,0.023046&amp;vpsrc=0&amp;g=245+Broad+Street,+Birmingham&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Jurys+Inn+Birmingham,+245+Broad+Street,+Birmingham&amp;ll=52.476756,-1.911515&amp;spn=0.020519,0.046091&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;cid=6378983717094669639&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="218" height="180"></iframe>
```

There are a lot like this. Any ideas on how to write the JS file that should apply to all of them? It´s a joomla site, so I need to put the JS code in a separate file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the answer above, I wanted to create styles to apply to all my maps. I didn't find a proper solution yet, but I've been reading this documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html and the map styling could be a partial help.

```
  map.mapTypes.set('pink_parks', pinkMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('pink_parks');
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier if you used the Maps API instead of just linking an iframe to a google maps page.

Comment: I intend to use it, but it generates a JS per map, and I need a dynamic solution instead... because it´s a Joomla site and the clients will be uploading maps all the time. Or did I misundestand the answer?